# C++/CLI code porting problem

Tags: c++-cli

I'm trying to port a `C++.NET` (managed extensions) application to `C++/CLI`. However I'm not very strong with the syntax yet.

What I'm trying to do is to create a wrapper for a `C Dll` file.

To do this I'm using DllImport but I failed to found documentation on it's use. There are some problems due to changes of the syntax but I couldn't find out why yet.

The `C++.NET` line looks like this:

```
[DllImport("my.dll", CharSet = Ansi,  CallingConvention = Cdecl, EntryPoint = "#10")]
 static MY_STATUS CPPInit(MY_HANDLE *pLmxHandle);
```

The idea is to pass a reference of `MY_HANDLE` to the function which initializes it. One problem is that the keywords `Ansi` and `Cdecl` are unknown. I expect I need to put some class infront of them but it's a little hard without docs or samples.

The other thing I have is a function which returns a static string:

```
char *MyFunc();
```

Can I assume that it can be mapped to `String^`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the first problem: just put `CharSet=CharSet::Ansi` and `CallingConvention=CallingConvention::Cdecl`, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7b93s42f.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.callingconvention.aspx

Comment: Second problem, use `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi`, see http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/554501-c-c-interop-returning-char

Comment: Why do you need PInvoke in C++/CLI, just call unmanaged function directly. PInvoke is for C#/VB programmers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the comment.

I thought to myself that I need to build a mixedmode library in order to avoid p/invoke. This just takes some time though.

Actually I solved the compile error in another way. Although I havn't tested it yet because I'm facing some 32/64 bit issues which I can't solve because of other bugs in Whidbey beta2.

My solution was to write the protype in the following way:

```
interior_ptr<MY_HANDLE> pMyHandle;
```

From what I understood it should give the function a reference (hence an address) to the dll function. Once I get to try it out I will see if my idea works.
Otherwise I will go for the following option (which i've been offered):

```
[Out] IntPtr p_MyHandle
```

Anyway I think the problem is solved because one of those should work.